# How to convert "\48\49" to "01" when its being printed out with string.gsub?

Tags: lua

So I have this basic script:

```
local a  = "|48|49"
a        = a:gsub("|", "\\")

print(a)
print("\48\49")

 -------OUTPUT-------
|  \48\49            | print(a)
|  01                | print("\48\49")
 -------OUTPUT-------
```

And I was wondering if there is a way I can make `a=a:gsub("|", "\\")` convert into `\48\49` and when its being printed out it will output `01` just like `print("\48\49")`.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: `local a = "|48|49"; a = a:gsub("|(%d+)", a.char); print(a)`

Comment: string literal -> rules to handle escapes -> string value.